# Android Null Pointer Exception on My Database

Tags: java, android, database, nullpointerexception, null

My insert function

```
public void AddBakim(){
    btn_bakimkaydet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            db.insertBakim("1","2","3");
        }
    });
}
```

My database function

```
 public boolean insertBakim(String bAd,String bFiyat,String bTarih){ /*String FK_aID*/
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues deger = new ContentValues();
  deger.put(COLUMN_bAdi,bAd);
  deger.put(COLUMN_bFiyat,bFiyat);
  deger.put(COLUMN_bTarih,bTarih);
  //deger.put(COLUMN_FK_aID,FK_aID);
  long sonuc = db.insert(TABLE_BAKIMLAR,null,deger);
  if (sonuc== -1)
      return false;
  else
      return true;
}
```

My other insert method doesn't work and is giving me the following error. Please help me friends.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
      at com.bakim.synergy.bakimson.BakimKayit.AddBakim(BakimKayit.java:42)
      at com.bakim.synergy.bakimson.BakimKayit.onCreate(BakimKayit.java:38)
```

Comment: looks like your `btn_bakimkaydet` is null, where do you initialize it?

Comment: can you add the code for `BakimKayit` class ? Because compiler finds error in that class.

Comment: ı solved thank you :) ı missed initialize, entery a incorrect null id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not initialized your button  `'btn_bakimkaydet'` . Please first initialize your button and then `setOnClickListener` on it.

Comment: I did it but not run :(

Comment: ohh thank you, ı control and I solved, I entry incorrect id :D